# How to append an item in a if-statement just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So every time I click the button to submit the form, the appended div appends itself over. How can I make it so the div appends itself just once?

```
<div class="field">
        <div class="field">
            <div id='eerr' class="errors"></div>
        </div>
</div>

if (email == '' || emailResult == false) {
    $('#eerr').append('<div class="ui basic red pointing prompt label transition visible">Please insert your email.</div></div>');
    }
```

Btw, this is the button:

```
<button style="margin-top: 7px" type="button" onclick='singup()' class="ui primary submit button login ">clickme</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for form validation, it sounds like you want the `#eerr` to contain all the warnings. There may be additional checks and warnings you want to add, so you might just clear the `#eerr` at the beginning of validation:

```
const $errorElm = $('#eerr');
$errorElm.empty();
if (email == '' || emailResult == false) {
    $errorElm.append('<div class="ui basic red pointing prompt label transition visible">Please insert your email.</div></div>');
}
// other validation involving $errorElm.append
```

Comment: Hey, it worked..  just that simple.. Now do you know how can I remove this message once user types the email correctly? once the email is incorrect again the message comes back up... How can I make that? Thanks tho

Comment: Just call `.empty()` whenever you want to empty the element